# to restore a copy of Exchange database from tapes

Tags: exchange-server

We have a test exchange 2003 server.  I was trying to restore a copy of Exchange database from tapes.  We have done this successfully many times in the past.

We usually stop the system attendent and information store and empty out the drive:\exchsrvr\mdbdata, and restart the system attendent and information store before we do a tape restore.

Last time, after I emptied the mdbdata, I was not able to bring up both system attendend and IS services anymore.

Do I need to reinstall Exchange running some special switches?  Any related document or steps we can follow do repair?

Please advise.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Run Eseutil /mh “Path of the database” and check the state of the database.

1. State= Clean Shutdown

Move log files from the Transaction logs folder location and mount the databse

2. State= Dirty Shutdown

Ensure that the log files required is in a Clean state by performing Eseutil /ml “Path of the log fileslog prefix” command

If the health status os ‘OK’ perform the Soft recovery with the command Eseutil /r  /l “Path of the log files” /d “Path of the database”

Mount the database after completing the operation

Sometimes the ‘/i’ switch is also used when the operation has failed to complete

If doesn't help, try to look at the answer here: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/843332/Trouble-reading-files-error-service-transaction-er